# Query Two data in Database using Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project that I want query two data in the firebase realtime database. The thing is , I am only getting one result in query that I want to make.
Like SQL for example

```
SELECT * JOBS WHERE PHONE EQUAL TO PHONE
```

I already understood that. And all I want is to combine where query the phone and query the date. I'm trying this, but the apps crash. Sorry for my bad English. I hope you guys understand what I mean.

```
public class CheckOrder extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Image";
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BothJobs, JobViewHolder> adapter;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BothJobs, JobViewHolder> checkadapter;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference jobs;


MaterialSpinner spinner;

String phone;
String flightDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_order);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    jobs = database.getReference("Jobs");


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listCheckOrders);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    phone = Common.currentUser.getPhone();
    flightDate = Common.currentUser.getFlightDate();

    if (flightDate != null)
        loadOrders();


}

private void loadOrders() {

    final Query jobsProject = jobs.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone);

    jobsProject.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot movieSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                BothJobs jobsCarrier = dataSnapshot.getValue(BothJobs.class);

                if (jobsCarrier.getTimestamp().equals(flightDate)) {

                    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BothJobs, JobViewHolder>(
                            BothJobs.class,
                            R.layout.check_order_layout,
                            JobViewHolder.class,
                            jobsProject
                    ) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(JobViewHolder viewHolder, final BothJobs model, int position) {

                            viewHolder.tvId.setText("ID : " + adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                            viewHolder.tvName.setText("Carrier Name : " + model.getName());
                            viewHolder.tvStatus.setText("Status : " + Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                            viewHolder.tvAirport.setText("Airport : " + model.getAirport());
                            viewHolder.tvAirlines.setText("Airlines : " + model.getAirlines());
                            viewHolder.tvLuggage.setText("Free Space Luggage : " + model.getSpace());
                            viewHolder.tvLocation.setText("Location Want To Go : " + model.getLocation());
                            viewHolder.tvPhone.setText("Carrier Contact : " + model.getPhone());


                            RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();
                            placeholderRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.profile);
                            Glide.with(getBaseContext()).setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageCarrier);

                            RequestOptions placeholderRequest2 = new RequestOptions();
                            placeholderRequest2.placeholder(R.drawable.wedee);
                            Glide.with(getBaseContext()).setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest2).load(model.getFlightDetail()).into(viewHolder.flightDetail);

                            viewHolder.btn_checkJob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    //Intent to ChooseJob

                                    Toast.makeText(CheckOrder.this, "Job" + model.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });


                        }
                    };
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });






}


}
```

I'm trying to match the also the timestamp equal flight date with phone equal to phone. But nothing appearing, i didn't get any crash for now.
[this image from "Jobs" ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9oVt.png)
[this image from "User" ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzG9e.jpg)

Comment: It seems that `timestamp` in `timestamp.equals(flightDate)` is `null`. There is no way for us to say why that is happening based on the information you provided. Check the definition of `BothJobs` (specifically its `timestamp` property) and the JSON you're reading.

Comment: its same name.. if im query only phone equal phone .. the result come out.. what im trying to do, put another query in same adapter.. is there any way?